# How services created through EJB Service annotation different from ServiceMBean(ServiceMBeanSupport)

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb

In J2ee applications, there are ways for creating services for containers like JBoss like using @Service annotation (https://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/docs/tutorial/1.0.7/html/Service_POJOs.html) 
  or ServiceMBean/ServiceMBeanSupport
 (https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/4.2/html/Server_Configuration_Guide/Using_JMX_as_a_Microkernel-Writing_JBoss_MBean_Services.html).

The service created using @Service/@Management can be converted to ServiceMBean/ServiceMBeanSupport and vice versa.

Is there any difference in terms of container deployment or how container treats them ? Or any other major feature which one provides over the other

Pardon i am a newbie in J2ee application development.

Regards